# parsing results in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have 2 query which give me the results:

1. service
2. number of service

example:

```
root@:~/elo# cat test  | grep name | grep -v expand | cut -c 22- | rev | cut -c 3- | rev
service1
service2
root@:~/elo# cat test  | grep customfield |  cut -c 31- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
2.3.4
55.66
```

I want to connect first value from first query with first value from second query etc. In this example should be:

```
service1:2.3.4
service2:55.66
```

Comment: You can write a bash script for this.

Comment: @rafal1337, could you please post sample Input_file of yours in your post and let us know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 this is json file. I parsing him to my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample file, it is hard to write a working example. But I see, both values are from the same text file and the same line. Therefore I would use *awk* to do it:

```
$ cat text
service1;some_other_text;2.3.4
service2;just_some_text;55.66

$awk -F ";" '{printf "%s:%s\n",  $1, $3}' test 
service1:2.3.4
```

For a JSON file, it would be easier if you can use *jg* (e.g. apt-get install jg):

```
$ cat test.json
[
  {
    "name": "service1",
    "customfield_10090": "1.2.3"
  },
  {
    "name": "service2",
    "customfield_10090": "23.3.2"
  }
]

$jq '.[] | .name + ":" + .customfield_10090' test.json | sed 's/"//g'
service1:1.2.3
service2:23.3.2
```

The sed is necessary to eliminate the quotes.

Comment: `{
...
            "name": "service1
...
        "customfield_10090": "1.2.3"
      }
    },
...
            "name": "service2"
          }
...     ],
        "customfield_10090": "23.3.2"` 
  
This is shortened json file.

Comment: In my case dont work - `jq: error (at test:42): Cannot index string with string "customfield_10090"` This is my entire json file: https://pastebin.com/gUU1x70j

Comment: You have to adjust the paths to the desired parameters: `jq '.issues[].fields | .components[].name + ":" + .customfield_10090' test.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste`:

```
paste -d: <(grep name test| grep -v expand | cut -c 22- | rev | cut -c 3- | rev) \
          <(grep customfield test |  cut -c 31- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)
```

But there might be better ways. If the input is json, you can probably use `jq` for a shorter and more efficient solution.